# PHP Login System Error Not appearing on page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, login-script, user-registration

I'm using notepad++ and Godaddy's phpMyAdmin to host the server. The file does not display anything when posted and whenever I put it in a PHP code checker it tells me this:

Error: There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' found This count is unaware if parenthesis are inside of a string)

and

Error: There is 1 more opening curly braces '{' found
This count is unaware if curly braces are inside of a string

Any help would be much appreciated.`

```
//Declaring them as variables
$username = $_POST["username"];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

//error handling
if((!$username) || (!$fname) || ($lname) || ($email) || ($pass1) || ($pass2))
{
    $message = "please insert all fields in theform below!";
}
else
{
    if($pass1 != $pass2)
    {
        $message = "Passwords do not match!"
    }
}
else
    //gathering the data
{
    $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
    $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
    $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
    $pass1 = sha1(#pass1);

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    //check for dublicates
    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check username");
    $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE username ='$email' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check email");
    $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0)
    {
        $message = "Your username is alread in use";
    }
    else if($count_email > 0)
    {
        $message = " Your email is alread in use";
    }
    else
        //insert the memebers to database
    {
        $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(username, firstname, lastname,email,password,ip_adress,sign_up_date)VALUES('$username','$fname','$lname','$email', '$pass1','$ip_address',now()")or die("could not insert");
        $member_id = mysql_insert_id();
        mkdir(,"users/$member_id",0755);
        $message = "You have now been registered";
    }


}
```

Comment: Please avoid using msyql_* functions. These are deprecated because they are unsafe and could lead to security issues if not used properly. It is recommended that you use mysqli or PDO (my recommendation is PDO).

Comment: `VALUES('$username','$fname','$lname','$email', '$pass1','$ip_address',now()` missing `)`. Also you can't `else` and `else`.. `}
else
    //gathering the data`. There are a few other issues here I would correct as well.

Comment: It's not "godaddy's" phpmyadmin.

Comment: It is still not appearing I forgot to include the top part. It now looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your else statement was misplaced. I moved it after the if statement where you check that the passwords match.

```
//Declaring them as variables
$username = $_POST["username"];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

//error handling
if((!$username) || (!$fname) || ($lname) || ($email) || ($pass1) || ($pass2))
{
    $message = "please insert all fields in theform below!";
}
else
{
    if($pass1 != $pass2)
    {
        $message = "Passwords do not match!"
    }
    else
    {
        //All required fields are filled
        //Paswords match
        //gathering the data
        $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
        $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
        $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
        $pass1 = sha1(#pass1);

        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

        //check for dublicates
        $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username ='$username' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check username");
        $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

        $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE username ='$email' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check email");
        $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

        if($count_username > 0)
        {
            $message = "Your username is alread in use";
        }
        else if($count_email > 0)
        {
            $message = " Your email is alread in use";
        }
        else
            //insert the memebers to database
        {
            $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(username, firstname, lastname,email,password,ip_adress,sign_up_date)VALUES('$username','$fname','$lname','$email', '$pass1','$ip_address',now()")or die("could not insert");
            $member_id = mysql_insert_id();
            mkdir(,"users/$member_id",0755);
            $message = "You have now been registered";
        }
    }
}
```